# Trouble adding new row in prettytable from saved txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and programming in general, so please bear with me if I am not explaining things correctly or using the proper terminology. Likewise, I probably won't understand you if you give me a very technical response. I'm trying my best, but this is new to me and extremely difficult!

I am trying to learn my way around python, so I started to create a little program that will track various things related to hiking, such as past hikes, mileage, etc. I found a library called prettytable which I installed and imported that formats data entered into a table. I got this working with data as it is entered, but not from a saved file. I want to be able to save the data that is entered into the program for later use.

Here's my module I am using that creates a list of hikes. Each hike has a destination, mileage hiked, days hiked, and partner. This part of the program is working as intended. After entering the info, the data entered is stored as a list called stored_words and then that list is added as a row to prettytable. The table is printed out after 
you are done entering hikes.

```
def Hikes():

    import prettytable
    import csv

    answer = "yes"
    Index = 0


    mytable = prettytable.PrettyTable()

    x = prettytable.PrettyTable(["Destination", "Miles Hiked", "Days Hiked", "Partner"])
    x.align["Destination"] = "l" # Left align destination
    x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)

    while answer == "yes":
        words = ["destination", "miles hiked", "days hiked", "partner"]
        stored_words = []
        HikeList = []
        hikesave = open("hikes.txt" , "a")
        for word in words:
            answer = input("Enter the %s:" % word)
            stored_words.append(answer)
            print(stored_words)

        HikeList.append(stored_words)
        hikesave.write('\n')
        hikesave.write(str(stored_words))

        x.add_row(stored_words)

        hikesave.close()

        answer = input("Enter another hike? yes or no: ")


    print(x)

    return x
```

Here's my module I created to load a file:

```
def LoadFile():

    import prettytable
    Flag = False
    FileToLoad = str



    mytable = prettytable.PrettyTable()

    x = prettytable.PrettyTable(["Destination", "Miles Hiked", "Days Hiked", "Partner"])
    x.align["Destination"] = "l" # Left align destination
    x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)

    print("-----------------------------------")
    print("     A = Hikes")
    print("     B = Miles List")
    print("     B = Destinations List")
    print("-----------------------------------")
    print()

    FileToLoad = input("Which file would you like to open?")

    while Flag == False: #Loop will keep running until true
        while FileToLoad == "A" or FileToLoad == "B" or FileToLoad == "C":
            if FileToLoad == "A

                with open("hikes.txt", "r") as f:   
                    lines = f.readline()
                    print(lines)                    

                x.add_row(lines)

##                f = open("hikes.txt", "r")
##                for line in f:
##                    print(line)
##                    x.add_row(line)


                print(x)

                Flag = True
```

I just can't figure out how to load the file (hikes.txt) in the LoadFile module and have the data inside that file added row by row to prettytable. When I try to do so, I get this error in my output:

```
-----------------------------------
     A = Hikes
     B = Miles List
     C = Destinations List
-----------------------------------

Which file would you like to open?A
['High Country Pathway, MI', '82', '4', 'solo']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\11-3-13.py", line 260, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\11-3-13.py", line 66, in main
    c = LoadFile()
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\11-3-13.py", line 216, in LoadFile
    x.add_row(lines)
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 818, in add_row
    raise Exception("Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) %d!=%d (expected)" %(len(row),len(self._field_names)))
**Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 48!=4 (expected)**
```

I do not understand why I am getting the above error.

This:

```
['High Country Pathway, MI', '82', '4', 'solo']
```

should be added to the row in prettytable... same format as used in the previous module.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I could not find any information on the error message I received and have been reading up on file input/output but cannot figure this out. I know there are probably a ton of things wrong with my code, but remember, I am VERY NEW to python and just trying to get things to work, so please don't be too hard on me.

**Edit

Stevha, I tried the code you supplied but I am still getting the same error, except now it's 7!=4:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\11-3-13.py", line 265, in 
    main()
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\11-3-13.py", line 66, in main
    c = LoadFile()
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\11-3-13.py", line 219, in LoadFile
    x.add_row(row)
  File "D:\Program Files\PROGRAMMING\Python\lib\site-packages\prettytable.py", line 818, in add_row
    raise Exception("Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) %d!=%d (expected)" %(len(row),len(self._field_names)))
Exception: Row has incorrect number of values, (actual) 7!=4 (expected)

I looked at pickle and JSON previously and didn't really understand what I needed to do. I thought the text file would work though. It works for printing the info, that's no problem, but so far not for inserting into prettytable. I was looking into csv importing also but was trying to get it to work with the text file first.

Thanks for your other suggestions as well. I was going to go through the code later when I got things working and do input validation and such, but for now I am just poking around, trying to get things to work. I'm exploring what I can and can't do with python, trying to see how things work. I know there's some unused code in there, like the HikeList list. I made that in an attempt to save data in different ways in the text file in hopes of getting past that error.

Here's what my program looks like when I am entering the data that is saved into the hikes.txt file:

```
    Choose from the list below: 

     A = Enter Miles Hiked
     B = Enter hiking destination
     C = Load File                        
     E = Exit program
--------------------------------------------------

Enter your selection:  b
Enter the destination:Big Bend, TX
['Big Bend, TX']
Enter the miles hiked:45
['Big Bend, TX', '45']
Enter the days hiked:5
['Big Bend, TX', '45', '5']
Enter the partner:Dan
['Big Bend, TX', '45', '5', 'Dan']
Enter another hike? yes or no: no
+--------------+-------------+------------+---------+
| Destination  | Miles Hiked | Days Hiked | Partner |
+--------------+-------------+------------+---------+
| Big Bend, TX |      45     |     5      |   Dan   |
+--------------+-------------+------------+---------+
```

The print statements are there temporarily so I can see what is being entered into the text file. After adding a new hikes to the hikes.txt file, it looks like this:

```
['High Country Pathway, MI', '82', '4', 'solo']
['Wemincuhe Wilderness, CO', '55', '6', 'Lisa']
['Big Bend, TX', '45', '5', 'Dan']
```

Each row in the text file contains a value for all 4 columns in prettytable in list format. The error is telling me that there are not 4 values, but isn't what I have a list, containing 4 values in each list? If it's thinking it's a string and not a list, then how do I tell python that each row in my hikes.txt files is a list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want some code similar to this:

```
with open("hikes.txt", "r") as f:   
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        x.add_row(row)
```

You can take the "open file" object `f` and use it for a `for` loop.  When you do this, the loop variable (in this example `row`) will be set to one line from the file and the loop body run.

By the way, when you prompt the user for input, you might want to do something like this:

```
choice = input("Which file would you like to open?")
choice = choice.strip() # remove leading and trailing white space
choice = choice.lower() # convert to lower-case
```

Then you can compare `choice` to `'a'` and `'b'` and so on, and it will be a bit forgiving (user won't need to upper-case, and if the user hits the space bar by mistake it will still work).

You can do the above all on one line:

```
choice = input("Which file would you like to open?").strip().lower()
```

EDIT: I don't really understand your code for saving hike data.  It looks like you are writing all the hike data at once and I don't think the way you are doing it will work.

I suggest you either write a very simple format, one line at a time, or else save all the data in a list and write the list using a library function.  The best choices would be Python's native `pickle` or JSON using the `json` module.

Assuming you want to write a simple format, CSV would be a good choice.  If you Google search for "Python CSV tutorial" you will find a lot of help, and there is a lot of stuff here on StackOverflow about it too.

EDIT: Also, it is clear you are very new to Python. I would encourage you to work through an introduction to Python, such as "Learn Python the Hard Way", or read a good Python book.

It's not 100% required, but it is a very good idea to learn the idioms of the Python community, and follow them.  For example, variable names should use lower-case letters and underscores; initial-caps should be reserved for class names.  This is written up in a standard called "PEP 8".  If you look at how StackOverflow has syntax-highlighted your code, you will see that `HikeList` is shown differently than other variables; this is because it is being flagged as a class name since it starts with a capital letter.

Also, my advice is to break up your program into small pieces and test each piece.  Have you tested that your file-creation code does what you wanted it to do?  Have you looked at the output file `hikes.txt` that you get when you are done?

Also, here is what that error message means.  You created a `PrettyTable` class instance, and set it up for a 4-column table.  So it expects each input row to be a list with 4 items in the list.  But you passed a string.  Python will pretend a string is a list of characters, so your `PrettyTable` instance saw a list of 48 things (each thing being one character).  My code example uses the `.split()` method function to split a string on whitespace, but you could use CSV with some other separator and it would probably be better.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the code you supplied and I am still getting the same error, but 7!=4 instead: